# Laravel 9 Bulk Insert Memory Leak

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, memory-leaks, bulkinsert

I'm trying to run a bulk insert in Laravel 9 via `Model::query()->insert($data)`, where `Model` is my model class. This works, and is much faster than using a factory to create many models, as the factory's implementation simply creates each model one at a time. However, I am experiencing a heavy memory leak specifically each time the call to `insert` on the Builder is made.

I'm using the latest Laravel 9.15.0 with PHP 8.1.6.

This can be reproduced in a Laravel Project using a simple model and couple migrations:

DummyModel.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\BaseModel as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class DummyModel extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "dummy_table";
}
```

`DummyModelFactory.php` (An empty factory)

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\DummyModel>
 */
class DummyModelFactory extends Factory {
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition() {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

`create_dummy_table.php`

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('dummy_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->char('name', 7);
            $table->foreignId('foreign_key');
            $table->string('long_string', 128)->nullable();
            $table->foreignId('target_id')->nullable();
            $table->date('date_performed');
            $table->dateTime('date_posted');
            $table->decimal('amount', 9, 2);
            $table->decimal('taxes', 9, 2);
            $table->boolean('closed')->default(false);
            $table->smallInteger('division');
            $table->smallInteger('acct_class');
            $table->smallInteger('group');
            $table->bigInteger('reference');
            $table->decimal('discount', 7, 2);
            $table->smallInteger('period');
            $table->foreignId('tax_group_id');
            $table->foreignId('batch_id');
            $table->string('comment', 1024);
            $table->json('extended');
            $table->dateTime('reversed_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dummy_table');
    }
};
```

`install_dummy_table`

```php
<?php

use App\Models\DummyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

return new class extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        $console = new ConsoleOutput();
        $data = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; ++$i) {
            $data[] = [
                "name" => "Test",
                "foreign_key" => 0,
                "long_string" => "a long string of text goes here",
                "target_id" => 4,
                "date_performed" => Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"),
                "date_posted" => Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d"),
                "amount" => 100,
                "taxes" => 0,
                "closed" => true,
                "division" => 0,
                "acct_class" => 4,
                "group" => 3,
                "reference" => 12345,
                "discount" => 45,
                "period" => 1234,
                "tax_group_id" => 4,
                "batch_id" => 7,
                "comment" => "A comment goes here",
                "extended" => '{}',
                "reversed_at" => null,
            ];
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
            DB::transaction(function () use ($i, $data, $console) {
                DummyModel::query()->insert($data); // <= Memory leak happens here.
                // DummyModel::factory()->createMany($data);
                $console->writeln("Iteration #$i, " . memory_get_usage(true));
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        //
    }
};
```

I am able to confirm that the memory leak happens when `insert($data)` is called by stepping through the program via xdebug, and watching the process' memory in Task Manager, and by seeing the migration's printout about how much memory PHP is using. Switching to the factory's createMany method stops the memory leak (memory usage has been constant through my tests), but is much slower in throughput due to inserting many models one at a time internally and not in one bulk insert.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in Laravel? I have a lot of large tables I need to import and process often, and would vastly prefer to have the option of a faster insert without the memory leaks. Attempting to purge the DB connection didn't reduce the memory usage, nor did using a single instance of the Query Builder (since `Model::query()` returns a new builder instance).

Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: i would try to do the other way around here in your loops. Instead of inserting 1000 record  per time and 100 times, i would try to insert 100 record 1000 time. In short try to reduce your data array first and then increase your insert loop, this way you keep the memory low

Comment: That did reduce the amount of memory it needed, but also slowed down execution some. I'm sure there's a fine balance to find the best batch size, but I'm struggling to understand why so much memory is being consumed by this and it's not being released until the migration command terminates, not just that one migration completes, if there are others.

Comment: try without transaction, sometimes it could lock the memory. Also you may try lazy collection instead of array

Comment: This uses a lazy collection via the `lazy` method, but I've recently been testing with using `cursor` instead of `lazy`, and it seems to be working a bit better since it isn't chunking a large collection in memory at once. Removing the transaction didn't seem to make a difference. It seems like I may just need to accept not-as-great-but-working performance using `cursor` and a smaller insert size. It's still much faster than using the factory's method of creating one model at a time. Still not sure what exactly is locking the memory in this, though.